# AVG Admin Server tie in with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, avg

Quick question,

Anyone know if the there is the ability to pull computer names out of AD and throw them into the AVG admin server list? Maybe through an API?

The AVG DB is < 100 items, and firebird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling them into the AVG admin server won't make them managed by the AVG admin server. You need to configure the AVG clients to communicate with the AVG admin server by setting the Remote Administration settings in the Advanced Settings on the client.